# NullReferenceException al llamar a una función C#

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando hacer una operación muy sencilla en Unity, en la que tengo un problema con el siguiente código:

```
public class Vida : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int hp = 100;

    public void RestarVida(int cantidad)
    {
        hp -= cantidad;
    }
}
```

```
public class Damage : MonoBehaviour
{
Vida v;
public int cantidad = 10;
public void mkDmg()
{
    v.RestarVida(cantidad);
}    
}
```

Quiero llamar a la función `public void RestarVida(int cantidad)` desde *Damage.cs*, y está definida en otro archivo *Vida.cs*. Al hacerlo me da este error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Contexto por si ayuda: Al clicar un botón tiene asignado un objeto vacío (*ButtonResponder*) con el script citado.

Imagino que será una tontería, porque no puede haber cosa más sencilla... pero estoy empezando en C# y vengo de Python... No sé qué me está fallando... Parece correcto.

Comment: Lo pruebo y marca error porque no se reconoce el tipo MonoBeahabord. Pero la solución puede estar cambiando v.RestarVida(cantidad); por Vida.v.RestarVida(cantidad);

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Alejandro! Pero Vida.v.RestarVida(cantidad);  da un error de compilado donde 'Vida' does not contain a definition for 'v'

Comment: Nose que haga eso de MonoBehaviour pero si hablamos de C# puro no puedes llamar al método de una clase sin haber creado la instancia antes, o  sea v = new Vida(); <--- sin la instancia no puedes acceder al método de instancia, pudieras poner public static Vida y public static void RestarVida(int Cantidad) y llamarlo:  Vida.RestarVida(cantidad); <-- con clases staticas no necesitas instancia

Comment: Puedes intentar crear la instancia:   v = new Vida();  despues llamar al metodo v.RestarVida(cantidad);

Comment: Cristina Carrasco. Me gustaría contactarte contigo por privado, ya que tengo un código que marca error y no sé como solucionarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Solucion instaciar el objeto v, de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Damage : MonoBehaviour
{
  var v = new Vida();
  public int cantidad = 10;
  public void mkDmg()
  {
    v.RestarVida(cantidad);
  }    
}
```